# Filter timestamp from sql database and extract as a list in python

Tags: javascript, python, sql, timestamp

I have an sql database from node red. The table of the database contains a column with javascript date.now() timestamps e.g. 1641154320892. Another column of the table contains temperature values. I'd like to select temperature values of a specific time period.

I tried the following code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/ktm/Developing/test/home_automation.db')
print ("Opened database successfully")
conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
c = conn.cursor()
ids = c.execute('SELECT Buero_temp FROM home_automation WHERE Zeitstempel BETWEEN '2022-01-05' AND '2022-01-07';').fetchall()
for i in ids:
    print (i)
```

Unfortunately, I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the exact `Traceback`

Comment: File "/home/ktm/Developing/sql_operations.py", line 13
    ids = c.execute('SELECT Buero_temp FROM home_automation WHERE Zeitstempel BETWEEN '2022-01-05' AND '2022-01-07';').fetchall()
                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You cannot have single quote `'` inside a single quote. Use double quotes instead.

Comment: `c.execute("SELECT Buero_temp FROM home_automation WHERE Zeitstempel BETWEEN '2022-01-05' AND '2022-01-07';")`

Comment: Nice, you've solved the syntax error problem! Great, thank you. However, It think there is still a little issue. Now it is working but the list "ids" are empty. Somehow nothing was selected...

Comment: Your ids will be empty. It is because, your data is in `epoch`, and your query is in string.

Comment: The type of the column Zeitstempel is in INTEGER e.g. 1641154320892. Do you know how I can select it properly? Unfortunately, it's the first time that I am working with SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly there is a syntax error.

A string in Python can be formed using both single and double quotes. If you want to use single quote within a string then outer string has to encapsulated with double quotes.

For eg:

```
my_string = "My string has 'single quotes'"
```

Now coming to your query:

As per your question the data stored in DB is in the form of timestamps, eg: `1641154320892`. Javascript uses 13 digits timestamp.

So you should query with timestamps.

```py
import sqlite3

def str_date_to_epoch(s):
    print(s)
    return int(datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp() * 1000)


conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/ktm/Developing/test/home_automation.db')

print("Opened database successfully")
conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
c = conn.cursor()
statement = f"SELECT Buero_temp FROM home_automation WHERE Zeitstempel BETWEEN {str_date_to_epoch('2022-01-05')} AND {str_date_to_epoch('2022-01-07')};"
ids = c.execute(statement).fetchall()

for i in ids:
    print(i)
```